# Exposed filter - in between operator

Tags: views

Okay, it's about a person height. 
I have a height field in my profile2 for user who select their height from a list text. Values look like this:

5'9"
5'10"

I would like to search users based on a height range. In the exposed filter block I have some pre-defined ranges such as:
5'6" - 6-0"
6'1" - 6'6" etc

And once selected it should display all users that fall into that height range

I had a similar requirements with age and I've managed to use the date field type for dob field and then use a field called age (with computed field type) to calculate the age and then use the "in between" operator in the "grouped filter" to filter different age group.

Here is a screen shot: 
http://grab.by/J73y

Issue with the height field is that it's not a date type, it's a mere string and hence I can't see "in between" operator.

So, how can I implement for the height field? any idea?